# Avoid pointers and #defines when programming in an Arduino?

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I was looking over the [StyleGuide](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StyleGuide) for the Arduino when I noticed that in the `Commenting your Code` section, it recommends to avoid using pointers and #defines.

Is there a reason the writer stated this? There isn't an explanation as to why he/she stated this. It doesn't make sense to me. Is this something specific to embedded systems?

Comment: Most likely because the style guide is aimed at making code "beginner friendly". I find it hard to take something that recommends `if (somethingIsTrue == TRUE)` seriously. Why not make it `if (somethingIsTrue == TRUE == TRUE == TRUE == TRUE)`?

Comment: Good point. Why mention them in the first place then? Beginners wouldn't necessarily even know about pointers/defines. Based off your response, I'm guessing he's just saying that to avoid any complications when learning to use the arduino, even if one is familiar with the concepts and has had experience.

Comment: @Mankarse: Because that's not enough `== TRUE`s in a row for it to be _really really_ funny.

Comment: @Mankarse: or `if(somethingIsFalse == FALSE == TRUE == FALSE == FALSE)`

Comment: Anything claiming to be a style guide should be taken with many grains of salt. Is it better to use tab indentation or spaces? Do you use brackets on single line if statements or not? At the end of the day who cares but don't avoid language features because they might be complex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know the specific reason the author wrote it, and I am not familiar with the library's written style - so I am going to answer in general terms of C++ programs.

I assume the preference is given because modern C++ typically favors other idioms, many of which were designed to avoid or minimize the issues frequently introduced by preprocessor and raw pointers.

**Avoid Pointers**

Instead of a pointer, it is conventional in C++ to use a reference for an object or a container such as a vector for a collection of objects.

```
//////// For an object
//// Using a pointer
bool getURL(t_url* const outUrl);
// In use:
bool result(obj.getURL(&outUrl));

//// versus using a reference
bool getURL(t_url& outUrl);
// In use:
bool result(obj.getURL(outUrl));

//////// For a collection
//// Using a pointer
bool apply(const double* const values, const size_t& count);
// In use:
bool result(obj.apply(array, count));

//// versus using a container
bool apply(const std::vector<double>& values);
// In use:
bool result(obj.apply(values));
```

Even pointers may be given object containers (auto pointer, smart pointer, shared pointer, weak pointer) because there can be a lot of complexity or ambiguity when dealing with with raw pointers, particularly in clients' code. It's quite rare that I write C++ programs that take or return raw pointers.

**Avoid Defines**

Preprocessor/defines are also not generally the preferred approach in C++ - you have inline functions, anonymous namespaces, templates, and enums.

The ubiquitous example of a macro that is problematic for many reasons is `#define max(a,b) ((a > b) ? a : b)`, versus `std::max`.

**Conclusion**

If I see a C++ program which uses a considerable amount of either, I find myself wondering in what decade it was written, or if the author was was writing in the "C with some more features" dialect.

Another answerer said the "advice is garbage". I disagree. The advice in Arduino simply says 'avoid pointers' and 'avoid #defines`. Of course, there will be times when you need to use these facilities, but you can write a clearer program when you use the language and library facilities which were intended to replace them (in the common ways they were misused or problematic). To *avoid* using them means to use them sparingly and only when necessary, favoring more modern and idiomatic alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

That advice is garbage -- pointers are an extremely useful and powerful tool, and quite often they're required in order to do something effectively.

`#define`s, on the other hand, should often be avoided for a number of reasons ([one](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html#faq-9.5) [two](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.4) [three](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.5) [four](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.6)) in favor of inline functions, but again there are many situations where macros should be used and are the best solution.  It depends on your problem -- be smart, and know when to use them and when not to.  Don't blindly avoid using them because some FAQ told you not to.

Comment: I found that references (explained as "aliases to other objects") are more easily understood by novices than pointers (which have a strange syntax and a lot of pitfalls), so avoiding pointers when you can use references could be a good advice (on the other hand there's the usual argument that with references you don't immediately see that a function call can alter the object you are passing - but if the interface is well designed it should be clear which arguments are going to be modified)